# How can I update a single array value using the useState()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to generate several checkboxes. I want that when you click on a checkbox the value of the `check` property changes to its opposite value. This would normally be done with:

```
check =! check
```

but I'm using `hooks`,

```
const [data,setData]=data;
```

and I don't know how to update this item without affecting the rest of my object. How can I do it?

this is my data, and my `hooks` definition:

```
        let data={
            "documents": {
            "trucker": {
                "checkDocuments": [
                    {
                        'label': 'licencia',
                        'check': false
                    },
                    {
                        'label': 'identificacion',
                        'check': false
                    },
                    {
                        'label': 'telefono',
                        'check': false
                    },

                ],
                "section": "camionero"
            },

            "client": {
                "checkDocuments": [
                    {
                        'label': 'comodato',
                        'check': false
                    }
                ],
                "section": "cliente"
            },
            "container": {
               "checkDocuments": [
                    {
                        'label': 'BL',
                        'check': false
                    }
                ],
                "section": "contenedor"
            }
           }
        }
        const [data,setData]=data;
```

this is the code that goes in the render

```
return (

    <List>
        {
            Object.keys(data).map((section, i) => {
                return
                <ListItem itemHeader first key={i}>
                   <Text>{data[section].section}</Text>
                </ListItem>
                data[section].checkDocuments.map((document, j) => {
                    return
                    <ListItem onPress={() => document.check = !document.check} key={j} > ***I need set only update this element in my data
                        <CheckBox checked={document.check} onPress={() => document.check = !document.check; }  color="blue" /> ****I need set only update this element in my data
                        <Body>
                            <Text>{document.label}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>
                })
            })
        }

    </List>)
```

How can I have the whole object that I defined in my hook updated from the modification of an element, so that my code is rendered again?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make yourself a compound state hook that can update individual keys. It would behave like the `setState` method in a React Class Component.

Check this out for reference: https://github.com/fvaldez421/shopping-demo/blob/master/src/hooks/common.js

If one level of interaction isn't enough, you can copy that key from your state, edit the copy, then use it to update your state:

```
const { state, setState } = useCompound(initialState);
const updateTrucker = (type, updates) => {
  if (type === 'documents') {
    const { trucker: truckerOriginal } = state;
    // copy it to prevent mutations
    const trucker = { ...truckerOriginal };
    trucker.checkDocuments = trucker.checkDocuments.map(
      doc => { /* your document check update logic here */ }
    );
    setState(trucker);
  }
}
```

The code above should update the `trucker` key in your state.